# How to simulate an HTTP 500 error on my React.js and Next.js apps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-500

I want to simulate this error so I can check a custom error page is displayed, not the HTTP 500 one, in light of the recent security vulnerability.

We include special processing in the site itself for 404 and 403 so I want to make sure that errors without special processing work too.

Comment: [Normally a 500 error is returned when the **server** throws an error that is not explicitly handled](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/error-handling#handling-server-errors). So creating a route that does `throw new Error("don't catch me, to return a 500")` should do the trick.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, thank you! It worked!

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer with two example. One for the `app`, and one for the `pages` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a 500 response is returned when the **server** throws an error that is not explicitly handled. (see: [Handling Server Errors](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/error-handling#handling-server-errors)). I've added two both `app` and `pages` scenarios down below. In both cases visiting `/error` should yield a 500 response.

---

If you are using the `app` API, adding a page that throws an error on the server should do the trick.

```
// app/error/page.jsx

export default function Page() {
  throw new Error("don't catch me for a 500 response");
  return <h1>you should not see me</h1>;
}
```

Make sure the component is **not** marked as client component (no `"use client"` at the top of the file). When marked as client component the error would be thrown by the client, not by the server. Thus not producing a 500 response.

---

If you're using the `pages` API a similar thing can be done. To run code on the server we use `getServerSideProps` (see: [Server-side Rendering (SSR)](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/server-side-rendering))

```
// pages/error/index.jsx

// this should run on the server
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  throw new Error("don't catch me for a 500 response");
  return { props: {} };
}

export default function Index() {
  return <h1>you should not see me</h1>;
}
```